# Error when installing ionic with npm install -g ionic cordova on windows 10

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

i'm trying to install ionic and returned this error:

```
95376 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.0.15 (node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
95377 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.15: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
95378 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
95378 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
95378 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   win32
95378 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
95379 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-afcbf2ea' -> 'C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
95379 verbose stack     at destStatted (C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:25:7)
95379 verbose stack     at C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:264:29
95379 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
95379 verbose stack
95379 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-afcbf2ea' -> 'C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
95379 verbose stack     at Error (native)
95380 verbose cwd C:\Users\<username>\Documents\sc-ionic
95381 error Windows_NT 10.0.14393
95382 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\<username>\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic" "cordova"
95383 error node v6.9.1
95384 error npm  v3.10.9
95385 error path C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-afcbf2ea
95386 error code ENOENT
95387 error errno -4058
95388 error syscall rename
95389 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-afcbf2ea' -> 'C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
95390 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-afcbf2ea' -> 'C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
95390 error enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
95390 error enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
95391 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

It is trying to rename some not existing directory "abbrev-afcbf2ea" in npm module.

Comment: try it by doing `npm cache clean` and reinstall them. i did installed it on windows 10, 2 hours back and it worked

Comment: try `npm install abbrev` then try o install `ionic`

Comment: Doesn't work neither of these solutions! :/  I've installed only ionic and works fine "ionic serve" on my app, but when i install "cordova" still returns  this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved **removing node_modules** folder and run:

```
npm install -g --save ionic cordova
```

I think that is a cache issue when something wents wrong in dependency installation of ionic + cordova that crashes the node_modules path!